# Typescript abstract optional method

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an abstract class with some abstract methods. Is there a way to mark some of these methods as optional?

```
abstract class Test {
    protected abstract optionalMethod?(): JSX.Element[];
    protected abstract requiredMethod(): string;
}
```

For some reasons I can add the `?` as a suffix but it seems like it does nothing at all because I have to still implement the method in the derived class. For now I am using it like this to mark it that it can return `null` which is basically the poor mans optional.

```
protected abstract optionalMethod?(): JSX.Element[] | null;
```

Comment: I don't think optional abstract methods are supported. See [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6413) and [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2947#issuecomment-125914985) for workarounds.

Comment: the correct answer is @idsbllp this is a unique feature of typescript and lesser known (merging the class and interface when they have the same name in the same file and both exported)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can do this with `class` and `interface` merging:

```js
interface Foo {
   print?(l: string): void;
}

abstract class Foo {
  abstract baz(): void;

  foo() {
    this.print && this.print('foo');
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  baz(): void {
    if (this.print) {
      this.print('bar');
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to the above code in the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=19&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRADlKGAPwAUANgFzIDOYZIA5gJQMBu6wAJgG4CAXwIE4AI2ZREYZAhpxGjNJhwEiUmXOSS4ALypdkvAcPybkMTMY2EiyMAAtgjAHSlyyAGQ+nrh5e4FQA5DbooRwWRGL4cQSKyqoAQnBQyBAAHpAg-KoYWHgO+kYmZvz2jsjAMMhULm6erGAcVdUBTcFgYfpQUTGOcbGiBEA)

Comment: upvoted - this is how React.Component is implemented when I checked thanks

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - you should make it clear that the Foo names have to match - the interface the class names.

Comment: How can you make those fields protected?

Comment: For reference: ESLint's "no-redeclare" rule doesn't like this merging, but `@typescript-eslint` has a parallel package with a config option to allow it: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-redeclare.md

Comment: This only works for public methods. To define optional protected methods the best way is described below.

Answer (score 49):

I'm not sure if this changed at some point, but today (TS 4.3) you can simply make the base-class optional method non abstract:

```
abstract class Base {
    protected abstract required(): void;
    protected optional?(): string;

    print(): void {
        console.log(this.optional?.() ?? "Base");
    }
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    protected required(): void { }
}

class Child2 extends Base {
    protected required(): void { }
    protected optional(): string {
        return "Child";
    }
}

const c1 = new Child1();
c1.print();

const c2 = new Child2();
c2.print();
```

Try it on the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgg3gFAIkIAOUA9hDvDgCYKiQzwJQ4COArgJYf0AFAEoAXAgBulXvQDcxUhWq0ajSmQi9KAO2DIA-CPEte2gObyFJCqYhHJ0xkVIukOsJWQ4AdMkpnBCAALXjBvdU0dPX1vEQR9fQQAImwwHCTheRcAX0JcwhQ0DABhEOR6AEYEHAAPGm16DFS8Z0UqGjpGDh5+BnspGQIEXPzC9ARS3nKAJmq6nAam3AIrcnaVBnYuPgF+xyHclyUO1QQIrV1kexNzFddSDghuKG1kyfKkrNIRwgL3RFgVQAvAhtDgAO4TMqVETyQHeGzaOyZX6wf5IWYgsGQ970aawgrTBFQWywoA).

Comment: While the other methods may have been the only/best way before, I believe this is the right way going forward!

Comment: This is the right way to go

Comment: It requires me to add override: `protected override optional(): string {` in the Child class

Comment: Jaime, that's an optional strict-mode setting called [`noImplicitOverride`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitOverride).

Comment: This is the best way! What's mentioned in the accepted answer only works with public methods, while this solution helps with protected methods as well.

Answer (score 13):

The concept of **abstract** is something which is not defined but will be in the inherited classes. That is why **we can't have abstract methods without implementation**.

I suggest you to create non-abstract method already implemented in your base class to achieve your goal:

```
abstract class A {
    protected abstract requiredMethod(): string;
    protected emptyDefinition(): string | void {};
    protected optionalMethod(): string {
        return "something optional";
     };
}
class B extends A {
    protected requiredMethod(): string {
        return "something required";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thought I could weasel myself with the `?` operator in the abstract method name.

Comment: Although this would work it requires to know implementation details of the abstract class for overriding certain methods which kinda defies the whole purpose of the abstract class.

Comment: on this case you always can cheat using an empty definition: protected optionalMethod(): string | void {};

Answer (score 10):

Typescript doesn't support the "omission" of optional abstract functions, but you can explicitly leave it undefined as below:

```js
abstract class Test {
    protected abstract optionalMethod?(): JSX.Element[];
    protected abstract requiredMethod(): string;
}

class MyTest extends Test {
    protected optionalMethod: undefined;

    protected requiredMethod(): string {
        return 'requiredResult';
    }
}
```

Comment: At least in TypeScript 3.8.3 (don't know when this first became available), you can now omit the optional method from the child class. It's treated as undefined by default.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need interface merging.
You only have to work with overload methods without default implementations like so:

```
abstract class Test {
    ...
    private someMethod() {
       ...
       this.optinalMethod?.();
    }
    ...
    protected abstract requiredMethod(): string;
    protected optionalMethod?(): string;
}
```

abstract indicated that it has to be overwritten in the implementing class.
in case of an optional method we however don't want to enforce overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been around for a while but and answered correctly above, but the example isn't clear. You can use interface merging like this too.

```js
interface Test {
    optionalMethod?(): JSX.Element[];
}

abstract class Test {
    protected abstract requiredMethod(): string;
}
```